# Difference between instruction reference and data refernce

Tags: cpu-architecture, numerical

I'm not able to get why 0.4 is used in finding miss rate of data cache rather than using 0.3 as it is also given that 30% of the instructions are data refernces.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJpC1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given fact is that there are `40 misses per thousand instructions for data cache`. Data cache will only be accessed for `Load/Store` instructions. There are only `40%` of `Load/Store` Instructions. Therefore in order to get the miss rate, you need to divide the value by `0.4`.

Comment: Yeah,i understand that but why, to find the miss rate for instruction cache we are doing (4/1000)/1.0=0.004. why we are dividing it by 1.0 and not 0.7 as it is given 70% instruction are instruction reference

Comment: when considering instructions, you need to use 1.0 because all are instructions, but when considering data you use 0.4 because only 40% instructions are related to data.